# pandas how create specific subset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My df looks like:

[image]

How create subset with 2 columns(State, Sum of all prices in this state) ??

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
df[["State", "Price"]].groupby(["State"]).agg(sum).reset_index()
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: thanks especially for doc links , how I can sort this data ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Give this a read.

Loads of stuff in the docs. Worth giving it all a skim through at some point.